# Twitter oAuth returns tweets and info but returns undefined index when I want to display them

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

```
$notweets = 5;
$search = '#potato';    

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

$search = str_replace("#", "%23", $search); 
$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=".$search."&count=".$notweets);

foreach($tweets as $status){
    echo $status['text'];
}
```

Hello again Stackoverflow!

I'm using TwitterOAuth to search twitter for some hashtags, in this example `#potato`. When I display `$tweets` it does return the latest tweets, but when I foreach and want to display them, it says I have an undefined index in the array, meaning it can't find `$status['text']`, although the path is right I think.

Can you guys help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your array access wrong? I don't know the API but I am thinking that $status['text'] doesn't have the text and it is probably something else.

Comment: @pratnala I guess so, but it's strange cause when I echo `$tweets` with `var_dump($tweets)` the path seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while passing it in a foreach loop you should do something like this.

```
foreach($tweets as $status) {
   echo $status->text;
}
```

Since the retrieved data is in json format you've to call the text as a object.

A similar code to retrieve user tweets is displayed [here](http://codedsack.com/get-user-tweets-php-twitter-api-v1-1/).